# Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation' in UpdateAsync (password reset)

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to apply 'Reset password' in my security application.

this the script to execute reset button

```
    $scope.resetPassword = function () {
        $http({ method: 'POST', url: 'api/tenant/admin/user/resetpassword', data: $scope.tenantUserPostModel }).success(function (response, status) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('inside response ' + response);
                noty({ timeout: 2000, layout: 'topRight', text: 'Changes saved successfully', type: 'success' });
                document.getElementById("passwordDetails").style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    };
```

my api

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/tenant/admin/user/resetpassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody]TenantUserPostModel model)
    {
        #region update azure ad user

        string userPrincipalName = model.UserName;
        if (!model.UserName.Contains("@"))
        {
            var DefaultDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultDomain"];
            userPrincipalName = model.UserName + "@" + DefaultDomain;
        }

        //*********************************************************************************************
        // update azure ad user
        //*********************************************************************************************
        var activeDirectoryClient = GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
        IUser userToBeUpdated = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User();
        try
        {
            List<IUser> users = activeDirectoryClient.Users
                .Where(user => user.UserPrincipalName.Equals(userPrincipalName))
                .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
            userToBeUpdated = users.First();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        userToBeUpdated.DisplayName = model.DisplayName;
        userToBeUpdated.GivenName = model.FirstName;
        userToBeUpdated.Surname = model.LastName;
        userToBeUpdated.AccountEnabled = model.IsActive;
        userToBeUpdated.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = model.TempPassword,
            ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = true
        };

        try
        {
            //error here 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation'
            await userToBeUpdated.UpdateAsync(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        #endregion
        return this.Ok(model.Id);
    }
```

screenshot of my [azure permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6LtZ.png)

I already click the grant the permission after enabling the 'Access the directory as the signed-user'

EDIT: I've added the method GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication. I don't if I'm doing it correctly or not.

```
    protected ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication()
    {
        Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(_GraphResourceId);
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, _Tenant);
        var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
             async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
        return activeDirectoryClient;
    }

    private string GetTokenForApplication()
    {
        if (ExtendedUserProfile == null)
            throw new Exception("initialize ExtendedUserProfile...");
        string AuthString = _AadInstance + _Tenant;
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthString, false);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_ClientId, _Key);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_GraphResourceId,
            clientCred).Result;
        string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }

    private async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication()
    {
        return GetTokenForApplication();
    }
```

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin?

Comment: @juunas yes the login user is 'Global Administrator'

Comment: But you are accessing Graph API as the application, not the signed in user right?

Comment: You could use https://jwt.io/ to decode your access_token and make sure the `scp` property has the related delegated permissions (`User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`) for [Reset a user's password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way this function is called: `GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();`

You are probably getting an access token with client credentials, i.e. as the application.
This means delegated permissions (like Access directory as the signed in user) do not apply.
Only application permissions apply.

You need to use On-Behalf-Of to exchange the access token your API got for an access token to Azure AD Graph API.
That will be a token in user context and thus delegated permissions apply.

- My article on the flow: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core
- Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of
- Example app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof

Comment: Well it confirms my guess. You are getting the token as the app, so delegated permissions do not apply.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what changes do i need to apply for this delegated permissions. tia

Comment: You can see a sample app here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs. That's the authentication config for the API. You can see how it acquires a token using on-behalf-of here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L125

Comment: Thanks a lot @juunas for the solution. I created new function to get the token using the sample code you provided. I owe you a lot!!